# Standard way of citing with authors name and theorem's name

Tags: citing

I am writing an article in mathematics using TeXstudio.

So, I was wondering if there is a standard way to cite a theorem which has a name.

For example,

```
\begin{thm}[ABC's theorem, Author 1, Author 2 \cite{key}]
     content...
\end{thm}
```

or

```
\begin{thm}[ABC's theorem \cite{key}]
     content...
\end{thm}
```

In my article, I have tried to put the authors' names before the citation number.

For example,

```
\begin{definition}[author \cite{key}]
```

So, in order to be consistent, should I use only the citation number or there is a different way of writing **name of the theorem, authors, citation number**.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Citation and cross-referencing conventions are heavily field-dependent. In which field do you work?

Comment: @Mico Sorry, I have updated my question. The field I work is mathematics.

Comment: Do you use any theorem-related packages, such as `amsthm` or `ntheorem`?

Comment: @mico I think so. I am quite new to LaTeX, and I am only using these packages amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,graphicx,mathtools. I don't know what the ntheorem package does.

Comment: The [amsthm](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) and [ntheorem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) packages do similar things. Incidentally, the [mathtools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package loads the [amsmath](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package automatically -- no need to load `amsmath` separately.

Comment: You may want to read pages 3 and 4 of the user guide of the `amsthm` package. For instance, the code snippet `\begin{lem}[Alinhac-Lerner \cite{a-l}]` produces `Lemma x. (Alinhac-Lerner [nn]).`, where `n` is the number of the lemma and `xx` is the citation call-out number.